# Чем отличаются функции _vsnprintf() и vsnprintf()

Tags: c, mingw

Я использую компиляторы `MinGW` и не могу понять, в чем разница между названными функциями. Попытался разобраться в комментариях заголовочных файлов `MinGW`, но смысл там написанного от меня ускользает.

Например, использование `Sleep()` в `MinGW` часто приводит к повреждению кучи/стека, поэтому рекомендуют использовать `_sleep()`.

Функции `_vsnprintf()` и `vsnprintf()` тоже чем-то отличаются?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vsnprintf` используется начиная с Visual Studio 2015 и соответствует стандарту C99; `_vnsprintf` осталась для обратной совместимости со старыми версиями Visual Studio.

[Источник](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/vsnprintf-vsnprintf-vsnprintf-l-vsnwprintf-vsnwprintf-l?view=vs-2017)

Comment: То есть, при использовании компилятора `MinGW` стоит использовать `vsnprintf()`?

Comment: Так понимаю, что да

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.